# Does there exist something that will programmatically add transformations to an existing PMML?

Tags: pmml

The statisticians I work with produce PMML in SAS and then deliver these to me.  They have to *hand code* transformations into the PMML and this process is time consuming and fraught with errors.

Does there exist something fulfills the following requirements,

1. Can be used by a non-programmer
2. Encodes transformations into an existing PMML
3. Adds items such as missingValueReplacement and invalidValueTreatment to individual variables
4. Can store the changes done to a PMML so that those exact changes can be done to a future PMML

Answer (score 2):

The closest to your requirements is [KNIME](http://knime.com). However, the "PMML editing" functionality is not part of the default installation, you need to download it separately from KNIME update site as "KNIME Modular PMML Nodes" plug-in.

This plugin will allow you define workflows, which 1) load an existing PMML file, 2) add the specified transformations to it and 3) save the result back to a new PMML file. Such workflows can be shared between team members.

The alternative to this is to develop programmatic transformers using the [JPMML-Model](http://github.com/jpmml/jpmml-model) library. It requires writing Java code (instead of working with GUI), but it will provide you with unlimited expressive power.

Answer (score 0):

One possible solution would be to use software produced by Zementis written for exactly this need. You can contact them here: http://zementis.com/contact/

This software takes the model only PMML, the SAS transformations commands and merges them into a final PMML file. It does the conversions and merge automatically and so should be easily usable by non-programmers!

Comment: Nothing I have read on Zemetis' site says that they can fulfill my requirements.  I keep getting pointed to their online [pmml transformation tool](http://www.zementis.com/PMMLTransformations/PMMLTransformations.html) which is a helpful learning tool, but cannot be part of a production workflow.

Comment: @0111001101110000, the transformations generator you are referring to is just to experiment with generating PMML expressions by hand. The product I am referring to is not available online, unfortunately you would have to initiate contact directly